# Построение списка от мин до макс значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть минимальное и максимальное значения:

```
min = 1
max = 7
```

Каким способом можно получить список диапазона значений от минимального до максимального (шаг единица), т.е.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Upd: И если шаг `0.5`т.е на выходе `[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4 и тд]`

Comment: @Jack_oS range  работает только ч целыми числами

Comment: @Danis спасибо, не знал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min = 1
max = 7 

res = list(range(min, max + 1))
```

а если вы используете python 2, то можно просто так:

```
res = range(min, max + 1)
```

---

для работы с не целым шагом используйте `np.arange`

```
import numpy as np

min = 1
max = 7
step = 0.5

res = np.arange(min, max + step,  step)
```

но numpy это очень тяжёлый модуль, поэтому место него можно использовать `numeric_range` из модуля `more_itertools`

```
from more_itertools import numeric_range

min = 1
max = 7
step = 0.5

res = list(numeric_range(min, max + step, step))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
min = 1
max = 7

my_list = [i for i in range(min, max+1)]
```

```
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

PS [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) и встроенная функция [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

UPD для нецелочисленного шага:

```
my_list = [round(i*step, 2) for i in range(min, int(max/step)+1)]

step = 0.5
>>> my_list
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0]

step = 0.35
[0.35, 0.7, 1.05, 1.4, 1.75, 2.1, 2.45, 2.8, 3.15, 3.5, 3.85, 4.2, 4.55, 4.9, 5.25, 5.6, 5.95, 6.3, 6.65, 7.0]
```

Comment: list(range(min_, max_+1))

Comment: @EzikBro пытаюсь найти, чем мой list comprehension хуже?

Comment: Спасибо, но если брать пример для нецелочисленного шага, то начало списка начинается с "непонятно чего", а с не минимального значения которое требуется

Comment: @Алексей блин, точно, нужно же от min... тогда def my_gen(), как у [Zhihar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/273314/zhihar)

Comment: `i*step + min`.

Comment: @Danis тогда первый элемент станет step+min, не от min, и верхняя граница увеличена... ```[round(i*step+min-step, 2) for i in range(min, int(max/step))]``` вот так, разве что... нет, при step=0.35 верх неправильный... да ну его, лучше функцией ))

Comment: `[round(i*step+min, 2) for i in range(int(max/step))] `

Answer (score 2):

> Upd: И если шаг 0.5т.е на выходе [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4 и тд]

```
def my_gen(limit_l, limit_r, step):
    value = limit_l
    while value < limit_r:
        yield value
        value += step


for num in my_gen(1, 10, 0.35):
    print(num)
```

**P.S.**

вот так чуть-чуть поточнее будет (не будет накапливаться погрешность)

```
def my_gen(limit_l, limit_r, step):
    index = 0
    while limit_l + index * step <= limit_r:
        yield limit_l + index * step
        index += 1


for num in my_gen(1, 3.5, 0.35):
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = []
>>> for i in range(1,15):
...     a.append(i)
... 
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```